# v-pagination not changing page

Tags: vue.js, pagination, vuetify.js

```html
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="agents"
  hide-default-footer
  pagination.page.sync="pagination">
  <template slot="item" slot-scope="props">
    <tr>
      <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.email }}</td>
    </tr>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
<v-row wrap v-if="agents.length > 10">
 <v-col xs="12">
   <div class="pagination-row">
     <v-pagination class="pagination" v-model="pagination.page" :length="pages" :total-visible="7"></v-pagination>
   </div>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

script

```js
data: function() {
  return {
    agents: [],
    pagination: {
      rowsPerPage: 10,
      page: 1
    },
    headers: [
      { text: 'Name', value: 'name'},
      { text: 'Email', value: 'email'}
    ],
  }
},
computed: {
  pages () {
    return this.pagination.rowsPerPage && this.inquiries.length !== 0 ? Math.ceil(this.inquiries.length / this.pagination.rowsPerPage) : 0
  }
},
```

Using the above code I am trying to implement pagination. But the issue I am facing is that if I click 2 to display the next 10 rows the data doesn't change. So basically pagination is not working. Please help me find where I am going wrong. I am using vuetify 2.3.10.

Comment: Have you found the solution? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are passing props for page incorrectly. Perhaps `pagination.page.sync="pagination"` -> `page.sync="pagination.page"` ?

Comment: still the page is not not changing